# How to override ignore_changes in Terraform?

Tags: overriding, terraform, configuration-files

I'd like to override an `ignore_changes`, like the one below.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile    = "default"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [instance_type]
  }
}
```

I'd like to override this configuration with one making the `instance_type` controlled by Terraform again. Is that possible? How do I do that? The configuration with `ignore_changes` should still exist and be unmodified.

Comment: Why not just remove it if you want Terraform to make the changes?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR because existing resources have had their `instance_type` manually modified and Terraform would crash everything if it was to change them.

Comment: So why not manually modify this one too?

Comment: if the instance type was manually modified, then seems like a job for Terraform state manipulation via `terraform state` and possibly `terraform import`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard look like an answer to me